# PrimeFaces Menubar not showing up (not converting to HTML)

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, menubar

The problem is that the

```
< p:menubar> ... < /p:menubar>
```

is being displayed in the actual web page instead of converting this into a menubar. The code snippet and page source is below.

Below is a simple main menu:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Main menu</title>
</h:head>
<body>
    <h:form>
        <ui:composition>
            <p:menubar> 
                <p:submenu label="home">
                    <p:menuitem  value="Home" url="/faces/home.jsf"/>
                </p:submenu> 
                <p:submenu label="doStuff">
                    <p:menuitem value="Do Stuff 1" url="#"/> 
                    <p:menuitem value="Do Stuff 2" url="#"/> 
                </p:submenu>
            </p:menubar>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

The page source when deployed is below (notice that the "code" from the xhtml file is coming through):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="EXPIRES" content="-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Mon,8 Aug 2006 10:00:00 GMT" />
    <title>Main Template</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="header" class="outerFrame">
    </div>
    <div id="navigation" class="outerFrame">
            <p:menubar> 

                <p:submenu label="home">
                    <p:menuitem value="Home" url="/faces/home.jsf"></p:menuitem>
                </p:submenu> 

                <p:submenu label="doStuff">
                    <p:menuitem value="Do Stuff 1" url="#"></p:menuitem> 
                    <p:menuitem value="Do Stuff 2" url="#"></p:menuitem> 
                </p:submenu>

            </p:menubar>
    </div>
    <div id="leftMargin" class="outerFrame">
    </div>
    <div id="rightMargin" class="outerFrame">
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="content">
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="outerFrame">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, feel like such a noob.  Forgot to add a dependency to prime faces in Maven.

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Welcome to stackoverflow ;-)